# keyup event in wpf listbox datatemplate

Tags: wpf

```
            <ListView SelectionChanged="RecordSelected" Height="134" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="processList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="record" DataType="{x:Type local:MyApp}">
                        <StackPanel Name="cell" Orientation="Vertical" KeyUp="cell_KeyUp">
                            <StackPanel KeyUp="cell_KeyUp" GotFocus="RecordSelected" KeyDown="RecordSelected" MouseDown="RecordSelected" Orientation="Horizontal" Tag="{Binding MyApp}">
                                <CheckBox BorderThickness="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="3,3,3,3" Name="checkbox" />
                                <TextBlock GotFocus="RecordSelected" HorizontalAlignment="Left" KeyDown="RecordSelected" Margin="3,0,0,3" Name="displayname" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

I added a KeyUp event on both the stackpanels inside the datatemplate, but it wouldn't fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `KeyUp` event won't trigger since it is the `ListViewItem` that has the focus. Subscribe to the `KeyUp` event in the `ItemContainerStyle` instead

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="KeyUp" Handler="cell_KeyUp"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the event handler the sender will be the focused `ListViewItem`. Cast `Content` of it to your source and toggle `IsChecked`. This will work if your source class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Otherwise, you can search the Visual Tree to find the child `CheckBox` of the `ListViewItem`

Answer (score 0):

Use the PreviewKeyUp event. That always fires.

You may also want to try PreviewKeyDown.

Comment: It didn't work. I want to check/uncheck the checkbox when the user hits the spacebar.

Comment: Hrm. Do any of the key events fire on it? It may be a focus issue.

Comment: I just checked and my PreviewKeyUp is firing. I'd look to see if it has focus, because I think it should be firing if it does.

Answer (score 0):

My awful solution: I used a mouse event since I couldn't get any key events to work.